# add javascript file with var object to angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

the object in the file look like this :

```
var DATA = {
    "groups": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "group xx",
        "devices": [{
            "id": 11,
            "active": 1
        }, {
            "id": 12,
            "active": 0
        }, {
            "id": 13,
            "active": 1
        }, {
            "id": 14,
            "active": 0
        }, {
            "id": 15,
            "active": 0
        }, {
            "id": 16,
            "active": 1
        }, {
            "id": 17,
            "active": 1
        }]

    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

The file format shown is JSONP. It has some support in Angular provided by the [JsonPModule](https://angular.io/api/http/JsonpModule)  - but its usage is *deprecated*. A better solution would be to serve the data in a JSON file and allow it to be accessed across domains (the original reason for JSONP).

You could also include the file in a script element provided you know what the preamble (`var DATA =`) is, accept creation of a global variable, and are aware of the security implications.